# How to set the text in span instead of div in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file

I am displaying the file name in div but i need to show file name in separate span as its multiple type file upload.

```
<div class="img_slt_inpt_outr1">
    <input type="file" class="img_slt_inpt1 edu_upoad" id="doc_brow" multiple/>
</div>                                          
<div class="certf doc_brow" id="doc_brow" onmouseover="myclsFunction()" onmouseout="myclsFunction()"style="color:#14b6f4;margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 10px;">

</div>
```

Uploaded filename will be displayed in class certf doc_brow as it is a div the multiple files appear in the div like :

[image: see in console]

but i need like  filename1  and  filename2

my jquery code is:

```
$('.edu_upoad').change(function () {
                    var file_id = this;
                    var class_name = file_id.id;
                    for(var s=0;s<this.files.length;s++){
                        Certificates.push(this.files[s]);
                        form.append("doc", this.files[s], this.files[s].name);
                        $("."+class_name).append(this.files[s].name);
                        $("."+class_name).append('<img style = "border:0px;width:20px;display:none;" id="clsimg" class="clsicon" src = "./images/closeRes.png" />');
                        $("."+class_name).append('<br/>');
                        console.log(form);
                        console.log(this.files[s]);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 $("."+class_name).append(this.files[s].name);
 $("."+class_name).append('<img style = "border:0px;width:20px;display:none;" id="clsimg" class="clsicon" src = "./images/closeRes.png" />');
$("."+class_name).append('<br/>');
```

To

```
 if (s > 0) {
     $("."+class_name).append('<span> And </span>');
 }
 $("."+class_name).append('<span>' + this.files[s].name + '<img style = "border:0px;width:20px;display:none;" id="clsimg" class="clsicon" src = "./images/closeRes.png" />' + '</span>');
```

What I did is wrap whole element in span tag

And if index is greater than 0 then added 'And' text